# Does 'when' suggest order of action when used in a present perfect sentence?

Tags: present-perfect

In
"I had eaten when he arrived."
Does that say that I finished eating first before he arrived?

Also, in
"I had eaten sea urchins when I went to Japan"
Does that suggest that I've already eaten sea urchins before arrival to Japan? Or does that say that I ate sea urchins while I'm in Japan?

Comment: It's the use of *already* (not *when*) that indicates an action having been completed. If you remove the *already*, it becomes ambiguous. (Although the more common interpretation is that the first action mentioned has been completed, that's only one interpretation.)